# Creating x86 bootloader

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader

I am writing a bootloader as follows:

```
bits 16
[org 0x7c00]
KERN_OFFSET equ 0x1000
mov [BOOTDISK], dl
mov dl, 0x0 ;0 is for floppy-disk
mov ah, 0x2 ;Read function for the interrupt
mov al, 0x15 ;Read 15 sectors conating kernel
mov ch, 0x0 ;Use cylinder 0
mov cl, 0x2 ;Start from the second sector which contains kernel
mov dh, 0x0 ;Read head 0 
mov bx, KERN_OFFSET
int 0x13
jc disk_error
cmp al, 0x15
jne disk_error
jmp KERN_OFFSET:0x0
jmp $

disk_error:
jmp $


BOOTDISK: db 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

The kernel is a simple C program which prints "e" on the VGA display (seen on QEmu):

```
void main()
{
 extern void put_in_mem();
 char c = 'e';
 put_in_mem(c, 0xA0);
}
```

I am using this code in 16 bit (real mode) in QEmu so I am using the compiler `bcc` for this code using:

```
bcc -ansi -c -o kernel.o kernel.c
```

I have the following questions:
1. When I try to disassemble this code, using

```
objdump -D -b binary -mi386 kernel.o
```

I get an output like this (only initial portion of output):

```
kernel.o:     file format binary

Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <.data>:
   0:   a3 86 01 00 2a          mov    %eax,0x2a000186
   5:   3e 00 00                add    %al,%ds:(%eax)
   8:   00 22                   add    %ah,(%edx)
   a:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
   c:   00 19                   add    %bl,(%ecx)
   e:   00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
   10:  00 55 55                add    %dl,0x55(%ebp)
   13:  55                      push   %ebp
   14:  55                      push   %ebp
   15:  00 00                   add    %al,(%eax)
   17:  00 02                   add    %al,(%edx)
   19:  22 00                   and    (%eax),%al
```

This output does not seem to correspond to the kernel.c file I made. For example I could not see where 'e' is stored as ASCII 0x65 or where is the call to `put_in_mem` made. Is something wrong with the way I am disassembling the code?

2. To make the object file of the kernel for QEmu I used the following command:

```
ld86 -o kernel -d kernel.o put_in_mem.o
```

Here `put_in_mem.o` is the object file created after assembling the `put_in_mem.asm` file which contains the definition of the function `put_in_mem()` used in `kernel.c`.
Then floppy image for QEmu is made using:

```
cat boot.o kernel > floppy_img
```

But when I try to look at the address 0x10000 (using GDB), where the kernel was supposed to be present after loading (using the `boot.asm` program), it was not present.
Why is this happening?
Further, in `ld` command we used `-Ttext` option to specify the load address of the binary, should we use some similar option here with `ld86`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `kernel.o` is in an object file format not understood by objdump so it tries to disassemble everything in it, including  headers and whatnot. Try to disassemble the linked output `kernel` instead. Also objdump might not understand 16 bit code. Better try `objdump86` if you have that available.

As to why it's not present: you are looking at the wrong place. You are loading it to offset `0x1000` (3 zeroes) but you are looking at `0x10000` (4 zeroes). Also note that you don't set up `ES` which is bad practice. Maybe you intended to set `ES` to `0x1000` and `BX` to `0x0000` and then you would find your kernel at `0x10000` physical address.

The `-Ttext` doesn't influence loading, it only specifies where the code expects to find itself.

Comment: Newer GNU objdump variants have the command line option "-M i8086" to disassemble 16-bit code instead of 32-bit code.

Comment: -Ttext option tells the linker to to offset the local addresses with the value we provide. Shouldn't this information be given to the linker to make appropriate addresses for the machine code when loaded in RAM?

Comment: I just said it won't affect if and where the code is loaded, which is the first thing to sort out.